# preserve Text Formatting in json and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, formatting

I have an api that I am using. It returns a list of a store's hours of operations.

I pull this data in php and return it in JSON to be parsed in Javascript.

By looking what is actually returned in chrome's inspect element from my php file that is called, it shows the JSON like this:

```
[{"lat":"33.1682803","lng":"-117.2198359","hours":"Retail Store\r\nSun: 12pm to 5:30pm\r\nMon: Closed\r\nTues: Closed\r\nWed: 11am to 7pm\r\nThurs: 11am to 8pm\r\nFri: 11am to 8pm\r\nSat: 12pm to 5:30pm\r\n\r\nTasting Room\r\nSun: 12pm to 5pm\r\nMon: Closed\r\nTues: Closed\r\nWed: Closed\r\nThurs: 4pm to 8pm\r\nFri: 4pm to 8pm\r\nSat: 12pm to 5pm","phone":"7605994225","name":"Tap House and Homebrew Shop"}]
```

AS you can see in the above JSON it keeps the formatting for new lines etc. in the hours.

I then parse my JSON with Javascript to display in HTML 5 like this:

```
var html = "";
            var lat = data[0].lat;
            var lng = data[0].lng;
            var hours = data[0].hours;
            var name = data[0].name;
            if(hours == ""){
                hours = "N/A";
            }
            var phone = data[0].phone;

            //create hours card
            html = "<div class=\"row\"><div class=\"col s12 m6\"><div class=\"card\"> <div class=\"card-content\"><span class=\"card-title black-text\">Hours</span> <p>" + hours +"</p></div><div class=\"card-action\"><a href=\"geo:" + lat + "," + lng + "\">Navigate</a><a href=\"tel:"+ phone + "\" style=\"float:right; \">Call</a </div></div></div></div>";

            $("#replace").replaceWith(html);
```

When the hours of operation are displayed they are jumbled together like this instead of on new lines each:

[image]

Comment: that's because `\r` and `\n` have no meaning in HTML - i.e. they don't effect layout - change your line breaks to html `<br/>` - you can do the change server side or client side, depends on what floats your boat

Comment: so basically parse the string and replace \n with <br\> ?

Comment: yes, that's what I was getting at

Comment: super simple thanks! If you want to post an answer I will give you credit for the help!

Comment: can use [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to parse to html